# Help using predict() for kernlab's SVM in R?

Tags: r, svm, kernlab

I am trying to use the `kernlab` R package to do Support Vector Machines (SVM). For my very simple example, I have two pieces of training data. A and B.

(A and B are of type `matrix` - they are adjacency matrices for graphs.)

So I wrote a function which takes A+B and generates a kernel matrix.

```
> km
         [,1]     [,2]
[1,] 14.33333 18.47368
[2,] 18.47368 38.96053
```

Now I use `kernlab`'s `ksvm` function to generate my predictive model. Right now, I'm just trying to get the darn thing to work - I'm not worried about training error, etc.

So, **Question 1**: Am I generating my model correctly? Reasonably?

```
# y are my classes. In this case, A is in class "1" and B is in class "-1"
> y
[1]  1 -1

> model2 =  ksvm(km, y, type="C-svc", kernel = "matrix");
> model2
Support Vector Machine object of class "ksvm" 

SV type: C-svc  (classification) 
 parameter : cost C = 1 

[1] " Kernel matrix used as input."

Number of Support Vectors : 2 

Objective Function Value : -0.1224 
Training error : 0
```

So far so good. We created our custom kernel matrix, and then we created a ksvm model using that matrix. We have our training data labeled as "1" and "-1".

Now to predict:

```
> A
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    0    1    1
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    0    0    0

> predict(model2, A)
Error in as.matrix(Z) : object 'Z' not found
```

Uh-oh. This is okay. Kind of expected, really. "Predict" wants some sort of vector, not a matrix.

So lets try some things:

```
> predict(model2, c(1))
Error in as.matrix(Z) : object 'Z' not found
> predict(model2, c(1,1))
Error in as.matrix(Z) : object 'Z' not found
> predict(model2, c(1,1,1))
Error in as.matrix(Z) : object 'Z' not found
> predict(model2, c(1,1,1,1))
Error in as.matrix(Z) : object 'Z' not found
> predict(model2, km)
Error in as.matrix(Z) : object 'Z' not found
```

Some of the above tests are nonsensical, but that is my point: no matter what I do, I just can't get predict() to look at my data and do a prediction. Scalars don't work, vectors don't work. A 2x2 matrix doesn't work, nor does a 3x3 matrix.

**What am I doing wrong here?**

(Once I figure out what ksvm *wants*, then I can make sure that my test data can conform to that format in a sane/reasonable/mathematically sound way.)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you think about how the support vector machine might "use" the kernel matrix, you'll see that you can't really do this in the way you're trying (as you've seen :-)

I actually struggled a bit with this when I first was using kernlab + a kernel matrix ... coincidentally, it was also for graph kernels!

Anyway, let's first realize that since the SVM doesn't know how to calculate your kernel function, it needs to have these values already calculated between your new (testing) examples, and the examples it picks out as the support vectors during the training step.

So, you'll need to calculate the kernel matrix for *all* of your examples together. You'll later train on some and test on the others by removing rows + columns from the kernel matrix when appropriate.  Let me show you with code.

We can use the example code in the `ksvm` documentation to load our workspace with some data:

```
library(kernlab)
example(ksvm)
```

You'll need to hit return a few (2) times in order to let the plots draw, and let the example finish, but you should now have a kernel matrix in your workspace called `K`. We'll need to recover the `y` vector that it should use for its labels (as it has been trampled over by other code in the example):

```
y <- matrix(c(rep(1,60),rep(-1,60)))
```

Now, pick a subset of examples to use for testing

```
holdout <- sample(1:ncol(K), 10)
```

From this point on, I'm going to:

1. Create a training kernel matrix named `trainK` from the original `K` kernel matrix.
2. Create an SVM model from my training set `trainK`
3. Use the support vectors found from the model to create a testing kernel matrix `testK` ... this is the weird part. If you look at the code in `kernlab` to see how it uses the support vector indices, you'll see why it's being done this way. It might be possible to do this another way, but I didn't see any documentation/examples on *predicting* with a kernel matrix, so I'm doing it "the hard way" here.
4. Use the SVM to predict on these features and report accuracy

Here's the code:

```
trainK <- as.kernelMatrix(K[-holdout,-holdout])  # 1
m <- ksvm(trainK, y[-holdout], kernel='matrix')  # 2
testK <- as.kernelMatrix(K[holdout, -holdout][,SVindex(m), drop=F]) # 3
preds <- predict(m, testK)  # 4
sum(sign(preds) == sign(y[holdout])) / length(holdout) # == 1 (perfect!)
```

That should just about do it. Good luck!

**Responses to comment below**

> what does K[-holdout,-holdout] mean? (what does the "-" mean?)

Imagine you have a vector `x`, and you want to retrieve elements 1, 3, and 5 from it, you'd do:

```
x.sub <- x[c(1,3,5)]
```

If you want to retrieve everything from `x` *except* elements 1, 3, and 5, you'd do:

```
x.sub <- x[-c(1,3,5)]
```

So `K[-holdout,-holdout]` returns all of the rows and columns of `K` *except* for the rows we want to holdout.

> What are the arguments of your as.kernelMatrix - especially the [,SVindex(m),drop=F] argument (which is particulary strange because it looks like that entire bracket is a matrix index of K?)

Yeah, I inlined two commands into one:

```
testK <- as.kernelMatrix(K[holdout, -holdout][,SVindex(m), drop=F])
```

Now that you've trained the model, you want to give it a new kernel matrix with your testing examples. `K[holdout,]` would give you only the rows which correspond to the training examples in `K`, and all of the columns of `K`.

`SVindex(m)` gives you the indexes of your support vectors from your **original** training matrix -- remember, those rows/cols have `holdout` removed. So for those column indices to be correct (ie. reference the correct sv column), I must first remove the `holdout` columns.

Anyway, perhaps this is more clear:

```
testK <- K[holdout, -holdout]
testK <- testK[,SVindex(m), drop=FALSE]
```

Now `testK` only has the rows of our *testing examples* and the columns that correspond to the support vectors. `testK[1,1]` will have the value of the kernel function computed between your first testing example, and the first support vector. `testK[1,2]` will have the kernel function value between your 1st testing example and the second support vector, etc.

**Update (2014-01-30) to answer comment from @wrahool**

It's been a while since I've played with this, so the particulars of `kernlab::ksvm` are a bit rusty, but in principle this should be correct :-) ... here goes:

> what is the point of `testK <- K[holdout, -holdout]` - aren't you removing the columns that correspond to the test set?

Yes. The short answer is that if you want to `predict` using a kernel matrix, you have to supply the a matrix that is of the dimension `rows` by `support vectors`. For each row of the matrix (the new example you want to predict on) the values in the columns are simply the value of the kernel matrix evaluated between that example and the support vector.

The call to `SVindex(m)` returns the index of the support vectors given in the dimension of the *original* training data.

So, first doing `testK <- K[holdout, -holdout]` gives me a `testK` matrix with the rows of the examples I want to predict on, and the columns are from the same examples (dimension) the model was trained on.

I further subset the columns of `testK` by `SVindex(m)` to only give me the columns which (now) correspond to my support vectors. Had I not done the first `[, -holdout]` selection, the indices returned by `SVindex(m)` may not correspond to the right examples (unless all `N` of your testing examples are the last `N` columns of your matrix).

> Also, what exactly does the drop = FALSE condition do?

It's a bit of defensive coding to ensure that after the indexing operation is performed, the object that is returned is of the same type as the object that was indexed.

In R, if you index only one dimension of a 2D (or higher(?)) object, you are returned an object of the lower dimension. I don't want to pass a `numeric` vector into `predict` because it wants to have a `matrix`

For instance

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(50), nrow=10)

class(x)
[1] "matrix"

dim(x)
[1] 10  5

y <- x[, 1]

class(y)
[1] "numeric"

dim(y)
NULL
```

The same will happen with `data.frame`s, etc.

Comment: Okay, so I ran your code as written, and it works! But I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what it does. Could you possibly help me understand: what does K[-noldout,-holdout] mean? (what does the "-" mean?) What are the arguments of your as.kernelMatrix - especially the [,SVindex(m),drop=F] argument (which is particulary strange because it looks like that entire bracket is  a matrix index of K?)

Comment: Since it was long, I responded to your comment in my original post -- read the bottom half. If you have more questions, you can always come to the r-help list to ask more questions. Lastly, if my response does answer your question, don't forget to mark it as such ;-)

Comment: @Steve Lianoglou thanks for that solution, it saved my day! I have very little knowledge about SVM and `kernlab` has very specific methods... however it is not clear to me whether I should include the response variable y to compute the kernel matrix? is there any way to "update" the kernel matrix without having to compute it again  when have new data? many thanks once again

Comment: @AP13: Don't get me wrong, but if you have limited knowledge of SVMs, you should do your homework to get a better understanding of how they work before just "blindly" using them. That having been said: (1) The kernel function is a funct'n of the features of your examples, and is independent from their labels, so you do not need `y` when computing the kernel matrix; and (2) it's possible, but you'd likely have to code up the solution yourself. The kernel matrix gives you the kernel values for each pair of examples (row,col). You'll need to create an "updated" kernel matrix that respects that.

Comment: @Steve Lianoglou thanks for your answers, I definitely will study the theory before using them.

Comment: @Steve Lianoglou that is one brilliant answer! However, I need one small clarification: what is the point of `testK <- K[holdout, -holdout]` - aren't you removing the columns that correspond to the test set? Also, what exactly does the `drop = FALSE` condition do?

Comment: @wrahool I am updating my answer to address your comment -- it is too long to fit into this comment box.

Comment: Great answer, and a bit late I admit, but should this method also work for `rvm`?

Answer (score 2):

First off, I have not used [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/package=kernlab) much.  But simply looking at the docs, I do see working examples for the `predict.ksvm()` method.  Copying and pasting, and omitting the prints to screen:

```
 ## example using the promotergene data set
 data(promotergene)

 ## create test and training set
 ind <- sample(1:dim(promotergene)[1],20)
 genetrain <- promotergene[-ind, ]
 genetest <- promotergene[ind, ]

 ## train a support vector machine
 gene <-  ksvm(Class~.,data=genetrain,kernel="rbfdot",\
               kpar=list(sigma=0.015),C=70,cross=4,prob.model=TRUE)

 ## predict gene type probabilities on the test set
 genetype <- predict(gene,genetest,type="probabilities")
```

That seems pretty straight-laced: use random sampling to generate a training set `genetrain`  and its complement `genetest`, then fitting via `ksvm` and a call to a `predict()` method using the fit, and new data in a matching format.  This is very standard.

You may find the [caret](http://cran.r-project.org/package=caret) package by Max Kuhn useful. It provides a general evaluation and testing framework for a variety of regression, classification and machine learning methods and packages, including [kernlab](http://cran.r-project.org/package=kernlab), and contains several vignettes plus a [JSS paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v28/i05/).

Comment: Right - I was reading ?predict too. In this example, you pass a kernel function ("rbfdot") and the training data ("genetrain") into ksvm(). In my case, my input is a kernel matrixm so ksvm() never has a "data" parameter, so there isn't a clear mapping between the structure of my training data and the structure of my test data.

Comment: If you are curious, I am trying to implement graph kernels into R - so rather than classifying vector data, I am looking at graph data. Thus, my kernel function looks at the number of random walks which are equivalent between two graphs to determine their "distance"

Answer (score 2):

Steve Lianoglou is right.

In kernlab it is a bit wired, and when predicting it requires the input kernel matrix between each test example and the support vectors. You need to find this matrix yourself.

For example, a test matrix [n x m], where n is the number of test samples and m is the number of support vectors in the learned model (ordered in the sequence of SVindex(model)).

Example code

```
trmat <- as.kernelMatrix(kernels[trainidx,trainidx])
tsmat <- as.kernelMatrix(kernels[testidx,trainidx])

#training
model = ksvm(x=trmat, y=trlabels, type = "C-svc", C = 1)

#testing
thistsmat = as.kernelMatrix(tsmat[,SVindex(model)])
tsprediction = predict(model, thistsmat, type = "decision")
```

kernels is the input kernel matrix. trainidx and testidx are ids for training and test.

Answer (score 0):

Build the labels yourself from the elements of the solution. Use this alternate predictor method which takes ksvm model (m) and data in original training format (d)

```
predict.alt <- function(m, d){
  sign(d[, m@SVindex] %*% m@coef[[1]] - m@b)
}
```

K is a `kernelMatrix` for training. For validation's sake, if you run `predict.alt` on the training data you will notice that the alternate predictor method switches values alongside the fitted values returned by ksvm. The native predictor behaves in an unexpected way:

```
aux <- data.frame(fit=kout@fitted, native=predict(kout, K), alt=predict.alt(m=kout, d=as.matrix(K))) 
sample_n(aux, 10)
    fit  native alt
1     0       0  -1
100   1       0   1
218   1       0   1
200   1       0   1
182   1       0   1
87    0       0  -1
183   1       0   1
174   1       0   1
94    1       0   1
165   1       0   1
```